# non empty element selected as empty

Tags: xpath

I have xml with a lot of appearance of following elements:

```
<attribute>
<attributeCode>aaa</attributeCode>
<attributeName>bbb</attributeName>
<attributeType>ccc</attributeType>
<attributeValue>ddd</attributeValue>
</attribute>
```

I use xpath expression to return  
    '//attribute/attributeName[attributeName="bbb"]' 
and it works fine, however I need to return attributeValue so I change to:
    '//attribute/attributeValue[attributeName="bbb"]'
I expect to get 'ddd' but it returns empty values. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you've selected the `attributeValue`, you need to go to the parent element first, to check for `attributeName`.

This will work (note: `../`):

```
//attribute/attributeValue[../attributeName='bbb']
```

Comment: Thanks! If it solves this/your problem, please click the tick, next to the answer.

Comment: sure will do. it does not give to accept earlier then 10 min :)